# Chosen selectbox refreshed one step too late

Tags: jquery

With a lot of help from the internet I managed to make a script that refreshes selectbox2 depending on what someone have chosen in selectbox1. The problem is that selectbox2 is one step too late.

I will try to explain it:
When i select London I want to see al the schools in London in selectbox2, but nothing happens with selectbox2. Then i choose Manchester, and than selectbox2 shows all the schools in London.

```
function fetch_select(val)
{
   $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: 'test_fetch_data.php',
     data: {
       get_option:val
     },
     success: function (response) {
       document.getElementById("wijk").innerHTML=response; 
     }


   }
   );

$(".chosen-select").chosen().change( function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
  $(".chosen-select").find('option[value="'+ selectedValue +'"]:not(:selected)').attr('disabled','disabled');
  $(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
});

}
```

If I don't use the chosen class everything works fine so I guess the problem isn't in the javascript.

Thanks in advance.

test_fetch_data.php:

```
   if(isset($_POST['get_option']))
{

 $state = $_POST['get_option'];
 $find=mysql_query("select wijk from geografie_wijken where plaats='$state'");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($find))
 {
   echo "<option>".$row['wijk']."</option>";
 }

 exit;
  }
```

The select part:

```
<select class="chosen-select chosen-select-deselect" name="plaats" id="plaats" onChange="fetch_select(this.value);">  
     <option value=""></option>  


         $select=mysql_query("select DISTINCT(plaats) from geografie_wijken");
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
         {
          echo "<option>".$row['plaats']."</option>";
         }


     </select>

  <select name="wijk" id="wijk" data-placeholder="Selecteer uw keuze(s)..."  multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select">
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you use? For example, how `fetch_select` is triggered? Also, plz html for selects.

Comment: Hi, i have added the other code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPD. To me it seems like the problem is due to this code

```
$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

being called before asynchronous ajax callback.  Try putting it inside `success` function, right after reassigning `innerHTML` of selectbox with response.

Comment: @Wouter How doesn't work: at all or still refreshes late?